# Kendo UI Grid - Add/Remove filters dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to Create a Kendo ui grid. Since this has many filters, I need to have 4 regular filters and rest should be able to add dynamically according to users choice. Can someone provide assistance on this?

Comment: OK. But  what you tried for this?

Comment: Few ways like adding a drop down and text box separately on data columns of the grid but there are couple of problems. Like I cannot avoid filtering for each drop down select . It should only happen if I type something in text box. Secondly I am unable to read what is the selected drop down value and typed Text in Text box. If these two are possible I can handle the rest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to filter by text box you can hook up a `keyUp` event in order to retrieve the value.  You can then add this as a filter to the existing `filter` object.

```
$('#NameOfInput').keyup(function () {
    var val = $('#NameOfInput').val();
    var grid = $("#yourGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var filter = grid.dataSource.filter();
    filter.filters.push({
        field: "NameOfFieldYouWishToFilter",
        operator: "eq",
        value: val,
        FilterName: "UniqueIdentifierForFilter"
    });
    grid.dataSource.filter(filter);
});
```

Using a drop down box, you can achieve the desired functionality by using the `onChange` event, get the value using `$('#yourDropDown').val();`.

The `FilterName` is optional incase you require additional logic to add/remove filters.  i.e. you can use this to determine whether the filter already exists in the array and if so you can use `splice` to remove it.

**EDIT**

Using `FilterName` you can search to see if a filter already exists and remove it:

```
var filterIndex = filter.filters.map((e: any) => { return e.FilterName }).indexOf("UniqueIdentifierForFilter");
if (filterIndex > -1)
{
    filter.filters.splice(filterIndex, 1);
}
```

Comment: In fact the drop down consists of other field names. As an Example, there is website, city, Province. If I select Province and Type "ONT" in Text box it should filter by Province with value ONT. If I select City and type "COL" It should filter by City and value is COL. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: If you want to filter the drop down datasource, you can set the [https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/serverfiltering](`filter`) attribute when initializing the component.  Optionally, you can use `filter: "contains"` if you want to return any item containing the input value.

Comment: filters.push({ this part gives an error. says push function is undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: I have made changes to incorrect reference of filters array. This will allow you to add to existing grid filters (instead of overwriting like your below solution)

Comment: Well don't forget to mark it as the answer if it worked ;)

Comment: Marked. one more thing. In my filtering with above way, I can see same field comes multiple times for a given query. Eg If I search for value a for company name and I delete it and type b secondly. my filter comes as company name =a and company name =b. I just need latest one only

Comment: I have added logic to check if the filter exists and,if so, remove it.

Comment: @Lakshan - I have posted an answer below which addresses undefined filter.

Answer (score 0):

For @lakshan, while this is largely correct, you will get an error if there are no filters at first. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014550/jquery-kendo-grid-filter-property-is-undefined/71400437#71400437) when I encountered the undefined filter error. My full solution for adding a filter, either to an undefined filter set, or along with an existing one:

```
var grid = $("#ActivityGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
var gridFilter = dataSource.filter();
var upcomingFilter = {
    field: "ActivityDate",
    operator: "gte",
    value: new Date(),
    FilterName: "UpcomingOnly"
};
if ($("#UpcomingOnlyCheckbox")[0].checked) {
    if (gridFilter == undefined) {
        dataSource.filter(upcomingFilter);
    }
    else {
        gridFilter.filters.push(upcomingFilter);
        dataSource.filter(gridFilter);
    }

}
```