# jquery kendo grid filter property is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a jquery function that should filter the datasource based on the Service Type value of the button that was clicked.

I used this post on telerik to get my guidance:

[Adding filters to Grid's source](https://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-filters-to-grid-s-source)

From that, I created this `buttonFilter()` function:

```js
function buttonFilter() {
    var buttonText = 'All';
    var button = $('#ReadTypeBtnGroup > button.btn.btn-default.active');
    if (button != null) {
        buttonText = button.val();
    }
    console.log('buttonFilter:: buttonText: ' + buttonText);
    var dataSource = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
    if (dataSource.filter() != undefined) {
        dataSource.filter().length = 0; // remove any existing filters
    }
    if (buttonText != 'All') {
        dataSource.filter().push({ field: "serviceType", operator: 'eq', value: buttonText });
    }
    return buttonText;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

The `filter()` property is supposed to be an array, but I am not great when it comes to javascript or jquery.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it wrong. You can't change filter properties changing the result of [`filter()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/filter) method. Instead, you have to use it passing parameters. That method only returns readonly values.

Example:

```
var filters = dataSource.filter(); // Getting current filters 
dataSource.filter(null); // Clearing filters
dataSource.filter({ field: "abc", value: "1" }); // Setting new filters
```

[Always check the docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/filter)

Comment: Is there any kind of way to debug why it still does not work? I have no bugs, but the grid is still not filtering. Should I create a new question or update this one?

Comment: @jp2code for debugging you can use raw source(not minified) version, but I dont think you need that. Are you using local or remote filtering ?

Comment: Um... local? I am on my development PC using a development SQL server. Is that local?

Comment: @jp2code nope. Local is when you have a loaded data(json) in your javascript scope and you pass it to the data source. Remote is when you setup your data source to request data to an API. Check [this out](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index), first two items after section *Data Binding*, binding to local and remote data, there you will get the difference. Anyway, when its remote you can check the filters in the ajax request and see if there is something wrong. When its local, its easier, probably a small detail you're missing cause its all javascript filtering internally.

Comment: It's remote, then. I am trying to create json data to display in the grid, but that is only after the data binding has finished. For what it's worth, I liked programming Windows Forms a lot more than trying to figure out javascript, client, server, DOM, etc.

Comment: Does the filter go before or after? Like `grid.dataSource.filter(xxx); grid.dataSource.read();` or `grid.dataSource.read(); grid.dataSource.filter(xxx);`??

Comment: @jp2code You can set a default filter in dataSource init parameters, or you can filter *after* data is loaded using that method. Another question, after data is loaded remotely, when you filter you want to hit the API again or use the same previously loaded data(which is in memory) ?

Answer (score 1):

@Dontvotemedown is largely correct, and that answer will work well for what you specifically want to do (i.e. clear filters completely and apply your own).  However, if you want to manually add a filter to existing filters, your original path was close to correct.  I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622074/kendo-ui-grid-add-remove-filters-dynamically) in my original search, then this when I couldn't add to an undefined filter.  My full solution for adding a filter, either to an undefined filter set, or along with an existing one:

```
var grid = $("#ActivityGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
var gridFilter = dataSource.filter();
var upcomingFilter = {
    field: "ActivityDate",
    operator: "gte",
    value: new Date(),
    FilterName: "UpcomingOnly"
};
if ($("#UpcomingOnlyCheckbox")[0].checked) {
    if (gridFilter == undefined) {
        dataSource.filter(upcomingFilter);
    }
    else {
        gridFilter.filters.push(upcomingFilter);
        dataSource.filter(gridFilter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If no filters exist, dataSource.filter() returns undefined which is a problem if you want to add filters. But using something like

```
dataSource.filter({ field: "abc", value: "1" });
```

results in a datasource read operation which was undesired in my case. Therefore I manipulated the datasource properties.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
var filterConfig = dataSource.filter();
if (typeof filterConfig == 'undefined') {     //no filters exist
    filterConfig = { filters: [], logic: "and" };
    grid.dataSource._filter = filterConfig;
}
```